# \newleadpage* compilation error in memoir

Tags: memoir, starred-version

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\newleadpage*{frontmatterpage}{Front Matter}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\frontmatterpage
\chapter{A}
\end{document}
```

If you try to compile this code, an error is thrown stating:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.2 \newleadpage*{frontmatterpage}{F
                                    ront Matter}
```

However when removing the `*` in `\newleadpage` the document compiles without any error.
Since the memoir documentation states that a `*` can be used with this command to avoid the addition of the page to the TOC. Can this error be resolved?

Comment: The documentation is incorrect. The definition of `\newleadpage` doesn't work with `*` in this way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage in the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) is incorrect. This becomes apparent when you look at the definition of `\newleadpage` (and `\renewleadpage`):

```
\newcommand*{\newleadpage}[3][empty]{%
  \@namedef{#2}{\@ifstar{\dlfm@msapppage{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
                        {\dlfm@mapppage{#1}{#2}{#3}}}}
\newcommand*{\renewleadpage}[3][empty]{%
  \@namedef{#2}{\@ifstar{\dlfm@msapppage{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
                        {\dlfm@mapppage{#1}{#2}{#3}}}}
```

It should be clear that there is no conditioning on `*`, as both macros take a single optional argument and two mandatory arguments.

You need the following definition/usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newleadpage{frontmatterpage}{Front Matter}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\frontmatterpage*
\frontmatterpage
\chapter{A}
\end{document}
```

Actually, the [`.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memoir.dtx) (commented code) contains a more appropriate description of the macro(s):

> `\newleadpage[<page-style>]{<cmdname>}{<title>}` creates new macros 
>   called `\cmdname` and `\cmdname*` that when called typeset a 
>   page like an  Appendixpage, with a title `<title>` using
>   page style `<page-style>` (default `empty`). The
>   plain version adds an entry to the ToC but the starred `\cmdname*`
>   does not. `\renewleadpage` changes the definitions.

Comment: Oh, thanks! As you explained, the memoir documentation is wrong on page 81 as there is no \newleadpage*. Lars Madsen should update the according documentation.

Comment: @PieterStroobants: I've sent a message to the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [maintainer](http://ctan.org/author/madsen).